# error: ‘registerrpc’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘register_t’?

Tags: c++, rpc

I need to create RPC Remote procedure call program in C++ using rpc.h library. The problem is even after I include it, I get error:

> error: ‘registerrpc’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘register_t’?

I must use `registerrpc` function, but I can not use it...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h> // included here
#include <rpc/xdr.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "i work";

    registerrpc(port,1,1,myfunction);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `myfunction` isn't defined anywhere, too. Have you looked inside those header files?

Comment: That has nothing to do with my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

`apt-get install libtirpc-dev`

and then:

`gcc -o server -I /usr/include/tirpc server.cpp -l tirpc`